# Excel Table Not Using Structured Reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2016

Using Excel 360. Every tutorial I see about Excel Tables assumed than when I create formulas inside a table, excel will use structured reference.. But I can't seem to make it do it that way? I type in "=" and then click on a table cell expecting the formula to use structured reference like =@[Cost] but instead it references the cell normally like =C3.. I don't understand what I'm missing? Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the formula behaviour in the Excel Options. Click File > Options > Formulas and tick "Use table names in formulas"

Oh, and it's Office 365, not 360.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The above post is correct. This is additional information which will help future users that were in my situation. Be sure the file is saved as the most current version in Excel. You may have to close/reopen the workbook (or Excel) to see the resolution.

Sorry to bump an old post, but I was unable to resolve this issue per the instructions. See the screenshots below.

[Option is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ID9b.png)

[Formulas are not as desired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UfZP.png)